# Loop for on dataset name in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

This topic has been covered numerous times I see but I can't really get the answer I'm looking for. Thus, here I go.

I am trying to do a loop to create variables in 5 data sets that have similar names as such:

Ech_repondants_nom_1
Ech_repondants_nom_2
Ech_repondants_nom_3
Ech_repondants_nom_4
Ech_repondants_nom_5

Below if the code that I have tried:

```
list <- c(1:5)

for (i in list) {

Ech_repondants_nom_[[i]]$sec = as.numeric(Ech_repondants_nom_[[i]]$interviewtime)
Ech_repondants_nom_[[i]]$min = round(Ech_repondants_nom_[[i]]$sec/60,1)
Ech_repondants_nom_[[i]]$heure = round(Ech_repondants_nom_[[i]]$min/60,1)

}
```

Any clues why this does not work?

cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are object names and not `list` elements to subset as `Ech_repondants_nom_[[i]]`.  We may need to `get` the object by `paste` i.e.

```
get(paste0("Ech_repondants_nom_", i)$sec
```

but, then if we need to update the original object, have to call `assign`.  Instead of all this, it can be done more easily if we load the datasets into a `list` and loop over the `list` with `lapply`

```
lst1 <- lapply(mget(paste0("Ech_repondants_nom_", 1:5)), function(dat)
     within(dat, {sec <- as.numeric(interviewtime);
                  min <- round(sec/60, 1);
                  heure <- round(min/60, 1)}))
```

It may be better to keep it as a `list`, but if we need to update the original object, use `list2env`

```
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thanks! It's always somewhat frustrating to find out that what you thought was almost right is so wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
Ech_repondants_nom_[[i]]
```

Isn't actually selcting that dataframe because you can't call objects like that. Try creating a function that takes a dataframe as an argument then iterating through the dataframes

```
changing_time_stamp<-function(df){
    df$sec = as.numeric(df$interviewtime)
    df$min = round(df$sec/60,1)
    df$heure = round(df$min/60,1)

for (i in list) {
    changing_time_stamp(i)
}
```

EDIT: I fixed some of the variable names in the function

Comment: If you like the answer can you please accept it!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I still get the following error message "Error in changing_time_stamp(i) : object 'Ech_repondants_nom_' not found"